# Set row height of range to 721px

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Sheet in PPT-Look which is filled with data from another sheet dynamically. Row height for rows 1 to 7 and from 30 to 36 are fix (header & footer of the ppt). In range from row 8 to 26, rows are hidden when empty (I entered white "X" to some of the rows to keep them shown).

[image]

I need to get a total height of 721px for the rows 2 to 36 to fit onto my PPT-Template when exporting it.

Is there a possibility to dynamically adapt row height of a "white" row (as for example row 29) to get a total of 721px for the defined range (row 2 to 36)?

Comment: Yes you can change check the row widths in a loop and adjust as needed, but you would need to show us code for us to fix that, we can't just go ahead and do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could go like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim extraRowHeight As Double, totalRowsHeight As Double
    Dim myRowsRange As Range
    Const maxRowHeight As Double = 409 '<--| maximum allowed row height

    totalRowsHeight = 721# '<--| set the total rows height you need for the range you are to specifiy right below
    With Worksheets("MyTableSheet") '<--| change "MyTableSheet" with your actual sheet name
        extraRowHeight = totalRowsHeight - .Rows("2:36").Height '<--| calculate the extra height needed for the wanted rows range
        With .Rows(29) '<--| consider the "reservoir" row
            If .RowHeight + extraRowHeight <= maxRowHeight Then '<--| if needed extra height leads to an allowable resulting "reservoir" row height ...
                .RowHeight = .RowHeight + extraRowHeight '<--| ... then adjust "reservoir" row height
            Else
                .RowHeight = maxRowHeight '<--| ... otherwise adjust "reservoir" row to maximum allowable height ...
                MsgBox "you still need to resize some other rows height for " & totalRowsHeight - .Rows("2:36").Height & " pts more" '<--|... and inform how much there still is to go
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I combined it with the code to hide empty rows between 8 and 26 and it works perfectly fine!